# Tweepy: How do you check if a tweet is favorited?

Tags: python, tweepy

I can check if a tweet is retweeted by me, but not if a tweet is favorited. Any solutions?

```
except tweet.id(retweeted):
        ignore
    except tweet.id(???)
        ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

````
id = 1272479136133627905
  
# fetching the status 
status = api.get_status(id) 
  
# fetching the favorited attribute 
favorited = status.favorited  
  
if favorited == True: 
    print("The authenticated user has liked the tweet.") 
else: 
    print("The authenticated user has not liked the tweet.")```
````

Comment: disregard the 3 backticks at the end -_-

Comment: also the id is the id of the status, which you would input yourself